# jQuery Mobile Form Validation with PHP Failing

Tags: php, jquery, forms, mobile, validation

I'm trying to add some validation to some form fields in a jQuery Mobile site I'm building with a PHP back end.

I've done this in the past successfully using the jquery.validate plugin but I'm having trouble getting this to work with jQuery Mobile.

The validation is working in this jsFiddle page:

http://jsfiddle.net/GeX5C/5/

but I'm having trouble getting it to fire when I click the submit button from the hosted PHP page. From what I've read I can't use the usual:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

approach but not sure what to replace this with?

Would really appreciate any assistance here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI this is js code that works for the form validation:

```
$('#id-for-the-page-element').live( 'pageinit',function(event){ 
  $('#id-for-the-form').validate(options);
});
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

2 options, in the event document ready is not supported for whatever reason..

one try the load event on the window, which will wait til everything is loaded and completely rendered, similar to the ready function but waits just that much longer course im paraphrasing but hopefully you get the point.. its applied the same as the ready function.

```
$(window).load(function(){
// Your code here
});
```

second option is dont use any load/ready. just make a function that fires off as the final line of your code, should whatever your doing truely not require the page to actually be fully rendered to run. logic to this is make a function then in the last lines call the function.

also try to keep a mass majority of your javascript especially pieces that require other things to load first at the bottom of your page just above the final body tag. Yea theres hot debate over this some people insist top is better while others insist bottom.. me Im a bottom guy think about the logic, when downloading the page downloads top to bottom in a sense correct? so.. put the heavier of the weight at the bottom such as external scripts. anyway im getting off point, hopefully this helps some what.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I think I've managed to get it working using the following:

Comment: Sorry the code is: $('#id-for-the-page-element').live( 'pageinit',function(event){ 
  $('#id-for-the-form').validate(options);
});